# Finding cardinality of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

How many distinct matrices are there in $M_{m\times n}(\Bbb{F}_2)$?

Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(\Bbb{F}_2)$. Then $A$ can be expressed as

$$A=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}E_{ij}$$

where $a_{ij}\Bbb F_2$. I think the answer would be $2^{mn}$. What I think is ' In each row $a_{ij} $ can be put in $2^n$ ways. So totol number of possibilities $=2^{mn}$'.

Is it correct?

Comment: $A=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}E_{ij}$ is an overcomplicated way to write $A = (a_{ij})$, may be this help you to count the matrices

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.  Even simpler, there are $mn$ entries in the matrix.  Each one has $2$ possibilities.  The multiplication principle says there are $2^{mn}$ possibilities.